Is arguing on Achronim an issue?
Since we are currently in the stage of "Achronim" is a current person halachikly able to freely argue on another "Acharon" like the Chafetz Chaim or the Aruch Hashulchan? Does it make a difference if he is a Rabbi or not?

How do we define “arguing on”? Is there a makor for that?
If we are still in the era of the acharonim we would need to continue a machlokes b’shem shamayim.

"we are currently in the stage of 'Achronim'" How do you know this?
